# How to display a chart from DataVisualization in Linqpad F#

Tags: linqpad

Using Linqpad 5.0, I have code that looks like this:

```
open System
open System.Net

open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization

open FSharp.Charting

...

module Chart = 
/// Creates a line chart from the given sequence using at 
/// most 'count' numbers and automatically adding X axis
let SimpleLine(seq, count) =
  seq |> Seq.truncate count
      |> Seq.mapi (fun i v -> i, v)
      |> Chart.Line

let chart = Chart.SimpleLine([1.0; 2.0; 4.0; 8.0], 3)
```

If I say

```
chart.Dump()
```

I see the typical Linqpad box, but not the chart itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function call works:

```
chart.ShowChart()
```